# How to process 2 FOR loops after each other in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

My problem is that two **FOR** loops are working separately, but don't want to work one after another.

The goal is:

The first loop creates XML files and only when the creation has already been done the second loop starts and counts the size of created XML files and writes it into .txt file.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\test\') do (
    echo Verarbeite %%~na
    jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml\%%~na.xml %%a
)

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml\') do (
    echo %%~ni %%~zi >> C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml\size.txt
)

pause
```

Comment: `CALL jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml\%%~na.xml %%a`

Comment: @Squashman That will probably have the same result as my answer.  If `jhove` never exits, execution won't continue.

Comment: @Squashman I added  CALL and it works the right way. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered easily when knowing what `jhove` is.

So I searched in world wide web for `jhove`, found very quickly the homepage [JHOVE | JSTOR/Harvard Object Validation Environment](http://jhove.openpreservation.org/) and downloaded also [jhove-1_11.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jhove/) from SourceForge project page of **JHOVE**.

All this was done by me to find out that `jhove` is a Java application which is executed on Linux and perhaps also on Mac using the shell script `jhove` and on Windows the batch file `jhove.bat` for making it easier to use by users.

So Windows command interpreter searches in current directory and next in all directories specified in environment variable `PATH` for a file matching the file name pattern `jhove.*` having a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` because `jhove.bat` is specified without file extension and without path in the batch file.

But the execution of a batch file from within a batch file without usage of command **CALL** results in script execution of current batch file being continued in the other executed batch file without ever returning back to the current batch file.

For that reason Windows command interpreter runs into `jhove.bat` on first file found in directory `C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\test` and never comes back.

This behavior can be easily watched by using two simple batch files stored for example in `C:\Temp`.

**Test1.bat:**

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
for %%I in (*.bat) do Test2.bat "%%I"
echo %~n0: Leaving %~f0
```

**Test2.bat:**

```
@echo %~n0: Arguments are: %*
@echo %~n0: Leaving %~f0
```

On running from within a command prompt window `C:\Temp\Test1.bat` the output is:

> Test2: Arguments are: "Test1.bat"
>   Test2: Leaving C:\Temp\Test2.bat

The processing of `Test1.bat` was continued on `Test2.bat` without coming back to `Test1.bat`.

Now `Test1.bat` is modified to by inserting command **CALL** after `do`.

**Test1.bat:**

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
for %%I in (*.bat) do call Test2.bat "%%I"
echo Leaving %~f0
```

The output on running `Test1.bat` from within command prompt window is now:

> Test2: Arguments are: "Test1.bat"
>   Test2: Leaving C:\Temp\Test2.bat
>   Test2: Arguments are: "Test2.bat"
>   Test2: Leaving C:\Temp\Test2.bat
>   Test1: Leaving C:\Temp\Test1.bat

Batch file `Test1.bat` **calls** now batch file `Test2.bat` and therefore the **FOR** loop is really executed on all *.bat files found in directory of the two batch files.

Therefore the solution is using command **CALL** as suggested already by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s "%USERPROFILE%\test\" 2^>nul') do (
    echo Verarbeite %%~na
    call jhove.bat -m PDF-hul -h xml -o "%USERPROFILE%\outputxml\%%~na.xml" "%%a"
)

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s "%USERPROFILE%\outputxml\" 2^>nul') do (
    echo %%~ni %%~zi>>"%USERPROFILE%\outputxml\size.txt"
)

pause
endlocal
```

A reference to environment variable `USERPROFILE` is used instead of `C:\Users\NekhayenkoO`.

All file names are enclosed in double quotes in case of any file found in the directory contains a space character or any other special character which requires enclosing in double quotes.

And last `2>nul` is added which redirects the error message output to handle **STDERR** by command **DIR** on not finding any file to device **NUL** to suppress it. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted on execution of command **DIR** and not as wrong placed redirection operator on parsing already the command **FOR**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`

And read also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `START` command with the `/WAIT` flag when you launch an external application.
I believe it would look something like this:

```
START /WAIT jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml\%%~na.xml %%a
```

That should cause the batch file to pause and wait for the external application to finish before proceeding.

Comment: it doesn't work. the external application can't be finished. it processes one pdf file already for 10 minutes

Comment: I'm not familiar with how jhove works, but if its process never actually exits, the batch file won't move beyond the `START` line.  The only other solution that I can think of would be to insert a sufficiently large pause, such as `TIMEOUT 10` to wait for 10 seconds, but that may be unreliable or flaky in other ways.

Comment: Some programs do not respect the /WAIT option.  CALL has always solved that issue for me.

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware that `CALL` could be used on external applications, I thought it only worked on built-in commands and subroutines.  You should add `CALL` as an answer.